# sum values of an object independent from the previous array

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hi I am trying to sum the value of `total_msg_send` of these objects, the first sum is good but in the rest of them it sums the previous result with the result of the next sum

[image: results]

This is the code that I have

```
this.groups = rsp['cards'];

 for (let index = 0; index < Object.keys(this.groups).length; index++) {
  const element = this.groups[index];
                
    this.apiSvc.receiveMessages(element.id).subscribe((rsp: any) =>{
      console.log(rsp); //object
      rsp.forEach(element => {

        this.sum += parseInt(element.total_msg_send);                
      });
        console.log(this.sum);//sum
                    
     });
                
 }
```

I'll appreciate if someone can help me, thanks

Comment: you need to reset ```this.sum``` back to zero before the API request.

Comment: There isn't any trace of TypeScript in this question. JavaScript is also not involved, you have a problem with the algorithm. Just reset the sum before processing each group.

Comment: Yes, you right Ashwyn Horton, thank you and thank to you too axiac, you can put that as an answer if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function on the array

```js
const reducer = (acc, value) => acc + parseInt(value.total_msg_send);
const sum = rsp.reduce(reducer, 0);
console.log(sum);
```